Instalación de wordpress de forma local fallida
al momento de tratar de instalar wordpress de forma local, usando XAMPP como servidor local. Si bien se instalo y permite usarlo, hay varias funciones que no me permite accesar, o que directamente no me aparecen en el wordpress, por ejemplo, el editor de temas, para poder modificar el código, o poder añadir CSS adicional. Esto lo veo bastante necesario, ya que los temas por defecto no son exactamente lo que busco, e incluso usando componentes en un tema en blanco no es como quiero tenerlo, por ejemplo, el encabezado aparece después de un espacio en blanco arriba, mientras que yo quiero que este totalmente arriba. Entonces, ¿es necesario hacer pasos adicionales a la instalación si se hace de forma local, con XAMPP y windows?

Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir, agrega más detalles

Realmente no se que tantos detalles podría agregar, pero, por ejemplo, al momento de dar click en la opción de editor de archivos de temas me aparece el texto "Disculpa, ese archivo no puede editarse.", investigando vi que al quitar la línea "$file = wp_normalize_path( $file );" del archivo function.php, en la carpeta includes, este error deja de pasar. Pero en si, el problema esta en que, cuando instalo wordpress en un servidor, me aparecen las opciones tal cual, pero al momento de descargar el zip para descargarlo en local las opciones no están completas, como digo, la de añadir CSS adiconal

También, en el servidor que instale wordpress use la herramienta que tiene por defecto, para el servidor local descargue el ZIP y lo instale como mencionan las instrucciones, creando la base de datos y poniendo la URL de la carpeta. Ambas versiones son el 6.5.5, la más actual, por lo que no tiene sentido, para mi, que haya diferencia entre las opciones disponibles, y esto sigue pasando sin importar la versión instalada

No necesitad el editor de temas si estas en local, solo crea un child theme de tu tema actual y haz las modificaciones ahi, pero si aun quieres usarlo, revisa las opciones en Tools o Herramientas, en las nuevas versiones se movio ahi o prueba con define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false); en el wp-config de tu instalacion

Esta parece más una pregunta de soporte que una pregunta entre desarrolladores. Si tienes instalado el sistema y quieres saber por qué tiene tal o cual comportamiento, podrías depurarlo paso a paso para averiguarlo tú mismo. Si no tienes esa habilidad, puedes ir al soporte del producto que utilizas o a algún sitio que tenga una comunidad de usuarios del mismo.

Si esta en herramientas, pero solo es accesible al quitar "$file = wp_normalize_path( $file );"  del archivo funtion.php. De cualquier modo ya se puede acceder, solo es cuestión de acostumbrarme al funcionamiento de wordpress, esta confuso como se distribuyen los archivos jeje gracias
